# SFTP hangs when listing a large directory from a Windows Server 2012R2 VM

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2016, ubuntu-16.04, sftp

I have two machines on the same ethernet network segment:

1. VM running Windows Server 2012R2 [sftp client]
2. Physical server running Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS [sftp server running openssh-server 1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.10]

When I establish an SFTP connection from the windows VM to the ubuntu server, when I try to list the files in a directory that has a large number of them, the connection hangs. Folders with small numbers of files work fine.

If I try the same thing using a different Ubuntu 16.04.7 machine as the client, it works fine.

Also tried a max size ping using `ping -l 1472 -f` and that worked correctly.

Things I have tried that didn't change the outcome:

1. multiple SFTP clients on windows: PuTTY 0.74, WinSCP 5.17.9, and FileZilla 3.52.0.5
2. lowering the MTU on the windows VM [default 1500]
3. lowering the MTU on the ubuntu server [default 1500]
4. updating the vmxnet3 ethernet driver from 1.8.16.0 to 1.8.17.0
5. using a different Windows Server 2012R2 VM as the client
6. using a Windows Server 2016 VM as the client
7. using a Windows Server 2016 physical machine as the client

I'm now stumped. Any ideas or suggestions for further troubleshooting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was in the middle of writing up a bug report for the PuTTY folks and was reviewing the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the Ubuntu 16.04 server. It had the line:

> `Subsystem       sftp    internal-sftp`

I changed it to:

> `Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server`

restarted sshd and now everything works properly!